# Mail applescript stopped working on Yosemite

Tags: macos, mail.app

This script stopped working in Yosemite. Any suggestion would be much appreciated.

```
tell application "Mail"
try


    set _msgs_to_move to (a reference to (every message of mailbox "INBOX" of every account whose flagged status is false and was replied to is true))
    set _msg_list to contents of _msgs_to_move
    if (_msg_list's length > 0) then
        move _msgs_to_move to mailbox "messaggi letti"
    end if
    -- End update for 10.7.0
end try
end tell
```

I get the following error:

> get every message of mailbox "INBOX" of every account whose flagged
>   status = false and was replied to = true
>   --> error number -1728 from
>   mailbox "INBOX" of every account

Thank you!

Michele

Comment: does it work with single account?

Comment: Good question! If I change this line like this it works on the account "myaccount":
  set _msgs_to_move to (a reference to (every message of mailbox "INBOX" of the account "myaccount" whose flagged status is false and was replied to is true))

So I Guess I'll have to find a way to add a overarching loop through all the accounts? If you know how to do it already you'll save me sometime.... other ways I'll look thought is when I have time...

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to  Buscar comment I solved it:

```
tell application "Mail"
set accountlist to the name of every account
try
    repeat with n from 1 to (the number of items in accountlist)
        set _msgs_to_move to (a reference to (every message of mailbox "INBOX" of the account (item n of accountlist) whose flagged status is false and was replied to is true))
        set _msg_list to contents of _msgs_to_move
        if (_msg_list's length > 0) then
            move _msgs_to_move to mailbox "messaggi letti"
        end if
    end repeat
end try
end tell
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you get the same results using

```
tell application "Mail"
set _msgs_to_move to every message of inbox whose flagged status is false and was replied to is true
    log (count of _msgs_to_move)

end tell
```

Comment: Yes it seems to work and it is much simpler! Thanks!